# Can Genji damage himself by deflecting Junkrat's grenades?

Tags: overwatch

Junkrat's ***Total Mayhem*** passive ability makes him immune to explosive damage from his own grenades. I was curious how this would work with Genji's deflect ability.

As a Junkrat, it would be hilarious if I could defeat a Genji by getting him to blow himself up while deflecting my grenades. I'd assume it's possible since the damage immunity is part of Junkrat's passive, but I haven't been able to test this myself.

**Can Genji damage himself while reflecting Junkrat's grenades if he's close enough or does Junkrat's perk prevent it?**

[image: Total Mayhem perk]

Comment: doubt it. 

No damage from explosive comes from Junkrat Passive, not his Grenade.

Comment: @TanyavonDegurechaff That's what I'm assuming as well, but I can't be certain.

Comment: Genji deflect works by erasing deflected bullet then generate new bullet.

so it's like Genji shooting grenade. & Genji doesn't have Total Mayhem passive

Comment: The only problem would be is that the junkrat has to get close enough to blow himself up

Comment: "Does Junkrat's perk mean that Genji can damage himself..." so your question is worded wrong.  Should say "Can Genji damage himself...." or "Does Junkrat's perk prevent Genji from damaging himself...."

Comment: @sirjonsnow I have reworded my question as-per your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Genji will take damage if the bomb explodes close enough to Genji and can kill himself. Since Genji doesnt have Junkrat's passive "Total Mayhem".

Comment: Have you tested this yourself, or are you assuming based on the in-game ability?

Comment: So YES instead of "nope" - if the rest of your statement proves true

Comment: @Steven yes i have tested this with my friends before the anniversary patch

Comment: It appears like genji does hurt himself from [reflected total mayhem grenades](https://gfycat.com/BlaringFlakyAchillestang)